# Autowired without component scan or setter/getter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to `@Autowired` a field

```
@Repository( "categoryDao" )
public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDao {
   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   ...
}
```

without using **setter/getter** or ***component scan**?

I have a config

```
<bean id="categoryDao" class="com.example.dao.SomeDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use constructor injection instead, so something like

```
@Repository( "categoryDao" )
public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDao {

   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Autowired
   public SomeDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }
   ...
}
```

There's a good discussion about the different types of injection, with a lot of refernce links available [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/)

*UPDATE after comment*

Now that you explained, you should not change your code on accout of test. In your case you should use a test specific XML context, but reduce the packages being scanned to just enough

Also a handy construct is that inside your test context xml, you can redifine some injected beans by instantiating it first and using `context:exclude-filter` property, usefull for mocking, an example snippet

```
<!--Mock object -->
<bean id="beanDAO" name="beanDAO" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="your.package.BeanDAO"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="your.package">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="your\.package\.Bean*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: My case is my production `applicationContext` is using component scan. What i'm trying to do is to test the `DAO` my code doesn't have any setter or getter and even a parameterize constructor. I want to load a lighter config file on each test. Is there another way?

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer, since in this context my answer has no real value. As said in the edit, you can simply use a copy of your applicationContext.xml stripped down of all the things that you don't need for your tests. Scanning should not be your immediate problem if you're scope the scanning for only what you need

Comment: Just one question before I accept. My applicationContext for testing is inside the `test source folder` I want to use a real `DAO` how do I map the package?

Comment: Just use the real package name, it will be visible for the test classpath as well